# Unable to use seaborn plotting features in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, matplotlib, scikit-learn, seaborn

I've written code to read in certain data from a CSV file, perform a PCA analysis on the data with the sklearn library, and then plot the resulting data as a heatmap. The code doesn't show any errors when run, but it also outputs no graph and just a line saying AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.62x0.77).

I'm wondering if Visual Studio is unable to display plots like this and if so what would be a better IDE for me to use for this project. If not can anyone see a problem that would prevent this code from displaying a heatmap? Copying the relevant code below

```
    import os
    import matplotlib as mpl
    if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
        print('no display found. Using non-interactive Agg backend')
        mpl.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import seaborn as sns
    sns.set()
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
    import pandas as pd

    # Scaling the data for PCA
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(data)

    pca = PCA(n_components = 2)

    pca.fit(x)
    finSet = pca.transform(x)

    hm = sns.heatmap(finSet)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: For python development any editor will do just fine. Else, try out whatever IDE you find and then come to a conclusion which one to use. Giving software recommendations is really totally subjective.

Comment: Out of curiosity since the IDE isn't the problem, do you see anything I'm doing wrong to prevent the heatmap from displaying?

Answer (score 0):

You may delete the lines

```
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using non-interactive Agg backend')
    mpl.use('Agg')
```

Those lines are intendet to query if the code is run in an environment which has a display. If no display is there, it should not try to create a plotting window on screen.

However, even if you have a display, but `os.environ` does not have a `"DISPLAY"` key, the code will falsely assume that no plotting window shall be created. This seems to be the case on Windows at least.

You might also want to inform the source of this code about their error.